# Should I approach my ex-manager in person to acquire an employer's referral?

Tags: referral, new-zealand

I need an employer's referral which includes the positions I held and my employment history.

- I have contacted this old employer of mine via their official website, no response.
- I have contacted the HR of this old employer on LinkedIn, no response.

As I am living in a different city now, there is no easy way for me to drop in personally, I am wondering if it is appropriate to contact my ex-manager on Facebook or LinkedIn to get my referral?

Alternatively, I could travel back and ask for it in person.

Thanks

Comment: What country is this? In the US, companies are required to verify title and dates of employment

Comment: @jcmack, my old employer is in New Zealand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say in a comment that your old employer is in New Zealand.

Having worked in multiple New Zealand companies, my experience is that you should **phone** your ex-colleagues and ask them if they are willing to be references for you.

No one would regard this as an intrusion, and you'll be more likely to reach them than by trying to hunt them down on a social networking site.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they seem active on LinkedIn I think dropping them a message on there is perfectly fine, given that is essentially what LinkedIn is built for.  (Career Networking and Development.)